# Apache Cassandra - Select Operation Timed Out

Tags: select, time, cassandra, out, operation

1. Installed --> datastax-community-64bit_2.2.7
2. Created --> Keyspace = INVENTORY and Tablename = Stocks
3. Able to pump in total 858 , 469 data records
4. System error to SELECT total of 858 , 469 data records

   > SELECT * FROM Stocks;

   Unable to execute CQL script on localhost: 
   [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Operation timed out
5. Here is Cassandra Keyspace and Table script creation:

   > CREATE KEYSPACE INVENTORY 
   >   WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};
   >
   > USE Inventory;
   >
   > CREATE COLUMNFAMILY Stocks (
   >   Id varchar,
   >   ProductId varchar,
   >   DealerGroupId varchar,
   >   SupplierId varchar,
   >   SerialNo1 varchar,
   >   SerialNo2 varchar,
   >   SerialNo3 varchar,
   >   PIN1 varchar,
   >   PIN2 varchar,
   >   PIN3 varchar,
   >   PIN4 varchar,
   >   PIN5 varchar,
   >   PIN6 varchar,
   >   ExpiryDate varchar,
   >   GRNId varchar,
   >   ProvisionedDate varchar,
   >   ModifiedDate varchar,
   >   MStockStatusId varchar,
   >   IsIntermediate varchar,
   >   ReStockOrderId varchar,
   >   ReturnRequestId varchar,
   >   AllocationOrderId varchar,
   >   PRIMARY KEY ((Id));

Comment: What if I am using Datastax DevCenter 1.5.0 --> an GUI interface to execute SELECT Queries ? Where I can adjust or configure the time out issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The default client timeout is 10 sec. If you are using CQLSH, you can configure in `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc`

```
[connection]
client_timeout = 3600
```

Generally, it is not recommended to select all with so many rows.
Hope this helps!

Comment: What if I am using Datastax DevCenter 1.5.0 --> an GUI interface to execute SELECT Queries ?

Where I can adjust or configure the time out issue ?

Comment: I have checked decompiled `com.datastax.devcenter.connections_1.5.0.jar`. It seems that DevCenter doesn't support customizing timeout.

Comment: What if I am using Helenos GUI Cassandra then can it handle customized timed out settings ?

https://sourceforge.net/projects/helenos-gui/

Comment: I checked the source code. https://github.com/tomekkup/helenos/blob/1.5/src/main/java/tomekkup/helenos/dao/model/ClusterConfiguration.java#L80

This tool also has no configuration. But if you want to you can change the source code and build it on your local.

Check Hector client timeout setting https://github.com/hector-client/hector/blob/hector-1.1-0/core/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/service/CassandraHost.java#L157

Answer (score 0):

I received Connection timeout while creating my first Keyspace itself. After lots of testing, i finally came upon a solution - follow the below steps in cqlsh

1. **desc keyspaces** --- This will list all system keyspaces present
2. **use system_schema;** --- Go to any keyspace, here system_schema
3. cqlsh:system_schema> **CREATE KEYSPACE ksp1
   ...   WITH REPLICATION = {
   ...    'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
   ...    'replication_factor' : 1
   ...   }**; ------------------- This will create 'ksp1'
4. cqlsh:system_schema> **desc keyspace**s
   cycling  system_schema  system_auth  system  system_distributed  system_traces
5. cqlsh:system_schema> **use cycling;**

Thanks,